# IRQ from Realtek WiFi are loading CPU

Tags: drivers, 16.04, cpu, realtek-wireless, interrupts

I have problem with my Toshiba Satellite C850-D3K laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 installed and RTL8723AE wireless adapter. The thing is that CPU consumption may go up after a while (30 mins - 2 hours) by no reason. See image below:

[image: htop screenshot]

```
$ cat /proc/interrupts 
           CPU0       CPU1       
  0:         43          0   IO-APIC   2-edge      timer
  1:       8809        535   IO-APIC   1-edge      i8042
  8:          1          0   IO-APIC   8-edge      rtc0
  9:         50         81   IO-APIC   9-fasteoi   acpi
 12:     115818      18613   IO-APIC  12-edge      i8042
 16:        326         30   IO-APIC  16-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1
 17:      14687  151826239   IO-APIC  17-fasteoi   rtl_pci
```

I suppose that the problem is wifi driver, because when I execute

`modprobe -r rtl8723ae rtl_wifi`

CPU consumption goes back to normal (not taking into account that wifi is not working anymore)

I've tried installing driver from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new but it didn't solve the problem.

The only way to solve the problem for me is suspend and wake up laptop each time that the problem appears. That returns CPU consumption to normal, but quite annoying.

I would be really glad if someone could help me with that.

Comment: I have the same problem on my msi laptop, currently with archlinux(kernel 4.19.4). I've also had it back when I was on Fedora, then it went away for a while(probably related to changes in kernel).